# Why there is so many functions in string.h library that are "not recommended for use"?

Tags: c, string, standards, history

There is something I try to understand about C origins, why there are functions that are not recommended for use in most of SO questions. Like `strtok` or `strncpy`, they are simply not safe to work with. Evrywhere I see recomendations to write my own implementation. Why wouldn't the standard change `strncpy` for example to BSD [strlcpy](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/strlcpy.c?rev=1.11), but is left instead with these "monsters"?

Comment: "Evrywhere I see recomendations to write my own implementation" - don't believe them. `strtok() -> strtok_r()`, `strncpy() -> memcpy()`, whatever. Reason #1: backwards compatibility. Reason #2: the C standard library is standardized (what a surprise), but nobody cares. Instead, OS and toolchain vendors keep rolling their own extensions.

Comment: Many of them are fine to work with if you understand their specific faults or limitations. e.g. `strtok` isn't thread-safe, but if you are just simple writing a single-threaded program then that's no problem. Likewise `strncpy` may be "unsafe", but it's fine to use with well-defined inputs. The key is to understand *why* certain functions have been replaced or deprecated. You can learn a lot by following the evolution of libraries like libc.

Comment: The issue with `strncpy` isn't a problem with "well-defined inputs", it's that the function isn't intended for copying strings to other strings. The purpose of `strncpy()` is to copy a string into a _null-padded fixed-sized buffer_. Not "null-terminated", but "null-padded". The target of the copy _is not a string_, it is a fixed-sized buffer. So, `strncpy()` is perfectly safe to use if you understand what you're doing, and the reason people will tell you "not recommended" is that it tends to get misused as a safer alternative to `strcpy()`, which it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is a product of the early 1970s, and it shows.  Many of the iffier library functions were written when the C user community was very small and limited to academia, most of whom were experienced programmers.

By the time the first standard was released in 1989, those original library functions were already  entrenched in 10 to 15 years' worth of legacy code (not the least of which was the Unix operating system and most of its tools).  The committee in charge of standardization was loath to break the existing codebase, so those functions were incorporated into the standard pretty much as-is; all that really changed was adding prototype syntax to the declarations and changing `char *` to `void *` where necessary (`malloc`, `memcpy`, `memset`, etc.).

AFAIK, only one library function has actually been *removed* from the language since standardization - `gets`.  The mayhem caused by that one library call is scarier than the prospect of breaking what is by now almost 40 years' worth of legacy code.

Comment: Loathe it all you want, but that won't make it go away.  I'm working on a system that really needs to be scrapped and rebuilt from the keel up, but that's never going to happen.  The real moral of the story is that history is a harsh mistress.

Answer (score 1):

There is a LOT of legacy "C" and "C++" code out there.  If they removed all the "unsafe" functions from the "C" runtime libraries, it would be prohibitive for many developers to upgrade their compilers because all the old code wouldn't build any more.

Sometimes they will give "deprecated" compiler messages (MSFT is fond of this) so you will find and change to using the new, safer functions.

New code should use the "safe" functions, of course, but many of us are stuck with old compilers and legacy code to maintain :)

Comment: Well, this is what I expected :) Also another reasons, I'd guess, for the lack of good C libraries is 1) Difficulty to write them 2) Most guys that do write in C use it for very hardware close operations, so they implement the smallest things they need and rest of their code deals with bit related logics.

Answer (score 0):

They still exist because of historical ancestral relationship with the "old system" / "codes" that still use them - i.e. to support "Backward Compatibility"

Own implementation is suggested to make the programmer use their own logic at their own risk as no one can know much better about their environment then the programmer himself, as for example, strtok is not thread safe.

Comment: "no one can know much better about their environment then the programmer himself" Isn't convincing at all. C meant to be a programming language, not an assembler, why reinvent the wheel each time if we can give everything the programmer will require, the same way as Java standard library does.

Answer (score -1):

It's all just dogma. Use the functions just be aware that they're indifferent to your goals in that they might not work in all circumstances (ie strtok and multi-threading) or they expect conditions to be caught before/after usage (ie strncpy and missing termination characters).